# Multiple callbacks in ava.js

Tags: javascript, ava

I have a callback that I want to see if its called twice.

I have looked into `t.plan` and in the [FAQ](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/when-to-use-plan.md#ensuring-multiple-callbacks-are-actually-called) it says its a good use case for `t.plan` but you have to explicitly define `t.end()`. But in my case its the same callback.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
test.cb('called twice', t => {
  let remaining = 2
  runCode(() => {
    remaining--
    if (remaining === 0) {
      t.end()
    }
  })
})
```